# Access Local Image through .ashx in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I am using an ashx file to retrieve an image from the database. 
If it is not available in Database it'll show another image which is inside my 
project folder. But I am not able to access the local image.
Can any body help me or suggest something?

My Code:

```
public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) 
{
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    string Value = (string)context.Session["UserID"];
    Stream strm = ShowEmpImage(Value);
    if (strm == null)
    {
        byte[] imageBytes = File.ReadAllBytes("~/images/photo_not_available.png" + context.Request["image"]);
        context.Response.ContentType = "image/png";
        context.Response.BinaryWrite(imageBytes);          
    }
    else
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int byteSeq = strm.Read(buffer, 0, 4096);

        while (byteSeq > 0)
        {
            context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, byteSeq);
            byteSeq = strm.Read(buffer, 0, 4096);
        }
    }   
   //context.Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
}
```

ThnnQ

Answer (score 2):

For sure you have a bug here, you add on the image file name, one more variable - this is for sure make a non existing file.

```
byte[] imageBytes = 
File.ReadAllBytes("~/images/photo_not_available.png" + context.Request["image"]);
```

a Second bug here is that you do not make MapPath of your ~

```
    byte[] imageBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(
content.Request.MapPath("~/images/photo_not_available.png"));
```

Or you can call it as @zapthedingbat suggest.

One more issue, you start with

```
 context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
```

and then you change it to

```
context.Response.ContentType = "image/png";
```

Comment: Thank You For your Quick respond. But i had tried this thing but it is showing "Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\MicrosoftShared\DevServer\10.0\~\images\photo_not_available.png'."

Comment: @SantoshSahu Correct because you use the symbol ~ but this function do not fix the path - this is a second bug.

Comment: Thanx Friend For your Help.
Ya it is not showing any error. But My image is not showing in the aspx page. Can you suggest where I have make the Bug.

Comment: @SantoshSahu try the zapthedingbat method, and if not work I write you some direct code, also remove the text/plain from the start point.

Answer (score 1):

Could you use the [HttpResponse.TransmitFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12s31dhy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method

```
Response.TransmitFile(context.Request.MapPath("~/images/photo_not_available.png"));
```

Comment: Thank You for your respond.But it is showing Error like "The name 'Server' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: @SantoshSahu call it with context.Responce.TransmitFile  Do not wait everything to solve by other, start thinking your code.